# GWT TabLayoutPanel into Disclosure Panel

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to add TabLayoutPanel into DisclosurePanel but when  I expand DisclosurePanel one tab only blinks and I do not see tab panel and its content: 
Here is my code:

```
      TabLayoutPanel tabPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(2.5, Unit.EM);


                  .....

                 I have FieldPanel which correctly works 
              for (Widget w : fieldPanelContent) {
                 tabPanel.add(w, "Internal");
              }

           }

        }

     }

  }

  tabPanel.setVisible(true);

  tabPanel.setTitle("My TAb Panel");
  tabPanel.selectTab(0);
  parent.add(tabLayoutPanel);
where parent is my DisclosurePanel
```

Could you please, help me to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing layout with non-layout panels. This is not going to work well, if you do not set the size of the `TabLayoutPanel` within the `DisclosurePanel` explicitly.

Comment: Yes, you are right! When I have changed TabLayoutPanel with TabPanel it works fine. Thank you very much!